# ASP.NET Web API - How to deserialize a JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume an API.
I want to store following Request in an Object: http://api.swissunihockey.ch/rest/v1.0/clubs/655
The Problem is, that the Object is initialized but all the values are null.

I can receive the data and generate an output as a string. But the De-serialization to the Object doesn't work. Can you help?

```cs
private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.swissunihockey.ch/rest/v1.0/clubs/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("615");
            var club = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Club>();
            Console.WriteLine(club.Name);
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            if (e.Source != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HttpRequestException source: {0}", e.Source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Club class I am trying to store the data:

```cs
class Club
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Canton { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722492/xml-string-deserialization-into-c-sharp-object). similar to your question

Comment: Can anyone explain the line `await client.GetAsync("615");`. What does 615 stand for?

Comment: The "615" stands for the ID of the object in the Rest API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another class containing Club which will be deserialized further.

```
class Response
{
    public Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as

```
var res = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response>();
var club = res.Club;
```

Comment: @Loki, can you explain the line `await client.GetAsync("615");`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the string from the response, use the package that Web API already references from Nuget, Json.Net by Newtonsoft.Json[1](http://www.newtonsoft.com/), and call `Club c = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Club>(responseString);`

I find this to be far simpler than the built in Data Contracts already mentioned.

Comment: Actually a combination of DRK answer and your line of code `Club c = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Club>(responseString);` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on the microsoft related documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

You need to create a data contract and then process the request with this contract.

For example for your, the data contract may be something like:

```
    [DataContract]
    class Club
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Street")]        
        public string Street { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Zip")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Canton")]
        public string Canton { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Then look at chapter "process the request" of the documentation to handle your data.

Comment: You don't need to create a Data contract for using REST api. In fact the Data contract breaks the RESTful philosophy of having loose server an client.

Comment: Wouldn't the "loose server and client" come into play when the service is consumed?