# How to get value of some object in XML string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML String :

```
<RESPONSE>
    <SINGLE>
        <KEY name="sitename">
            <VALUE>Stackoverflow</VALUE>
        </KEY>
        <KEY name="username">
            <VALUE>this value</VALUE>
        </KEY>
    </SINGLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

How to get value from Key that name "username" ? I want to get value of "this value" in my code. I try deserialized and any other code but it doesnt work. Please help me, thanks :D

Edit:

I tried using this code :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "myXML.xml" );

var keys = doc.Descendants( "KEY" );

foreach ( var VALUE in keys )
{
    Console.WriteLine( VALUE.Value );
}
```

But how did I get the Value only from KEY that named "Username" ? Thanks :))

Comment: What are you doing so far?

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml

Comment: Normally you will try to get a Value from a concrete Key, in this case your are doing the opposite...

Comment: have you tried googling...?

Comment: I tried using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722492/xml-string-deserialization-into-c-sharp-object and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/c-sharp-convert-xml-string-to-object code but it doesnt work. I confuse because i must get an object inside of Value inside of Key inside of Single. How ? :"

Comment: I tried googling of course

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand here. But I am correct that the questioner wants the program to output: "this value"? Or do you want it to output "username"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness here is a System.Xml.Linq version, with the foreachs and where's being System.Linq for good measure. This basically the questioner's attempt, with a where to filter according to attribute.

```
const string example_xml = "<RESPONSE> <SINGLE> <KEY name=\"sitename\"> <VALUE>Stackoverflow</VALUE> </KEY> <KEY name=\"username\"> <VALUE>this value</VALUE> </KEY> </SINGLE> </RESPONSE>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(example_xml);
var keys = doc.Descendants("KEY");
var userKeys = keys.Where(item => item.Attribute("name").Value == "username").ToList();
userKeys.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Value));
```

Comment: Sorry drew_w, I was lazy and nicked your string.

Comment: Can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430357/how-to-get-xml-web-service-response-in-c-sharp) regarding the xml response?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use an xpath to do this. The following is an example XPath that will provide a node with name matching "sitename":

```
//KEY[@name="sitename"]
```

You can modify this slightly to find all nodes with a "name" attribute or to just find specific names. For more examples of how to use XPath see the [MSDN site for XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The following is a snippet of C# code that shows you how to use this XPath (again, you can generalize for whatever XPath you need):

```
const string example_xml = "<RESPONSE> <SINGLE> <KEY name=\"sitename\"> <VALUE>Stackoverflow</VALUE> </KEY> <KEY name=\"username\"> <VALUE>this value</VALUE> </KEY> </SINGLE> </RESPONSE>";

// load
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(example_xml);

// Query single or multiple nodes using the XPath, do what you want with this node!
var desiredNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//KEY[@name=\"sitename\"]");
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider your xml document as XYZ.xml, then you may try below code if you are using C#, below is the example only

```
       XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.Load(Server.MapPath(".../xyz.xml"));
         XmlNodeList itemList = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("KEY");
         foreach (XmlNode currNode in itemList)
         {
             string name = string.Empty; 
             XmlNode item = currNode.SelectSingleNode("KEY");
             if(currNode["name"].InnerText == "username")//if you are aware of key name, use this       condition
             {
               name = item.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString(); // or currNode["name"].InnerText;
             }
          }
```